# Matlab script to monitor and read images from mySQL DB and save its result to MySQL databse

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, matlab

Hello Im trying to write a matlab script that can fetch images for mySQL database -> Process them & send their result to another table.
 I have already install JDBC driver and here is my script so far..

```
function [res] = photom()
conn = database('e_gardener','root','',...
'Vendor','MySQL',...
'Server','localhost');
srcFiles = dir('C:\xampp\htdocs\V\uploads\*.png');  % the folder in which ur images exists
for k=1:100 %suppose there are 10 image
file_name= strcat('C:\xampp\htdocs\V\uploads\',srcFiles(k).name); % the path tht u have imges
  IM = imread(file_name); 
  res = Detect(IM);
  disp(res);
 datainsert(conn,'photo',{'Result'},{res})
end
end
```

The problem with this script is.. its gets breaked when there are less then 100 images in database..

I want to write a script that can only fetch unprocessed images from database and can only when new images in data base is inserted..
in short i want my script to work as a web application.. by which if more than one user send image to database it should work ok..

im uploading these images from a android mobile application by which user can upload its image to mySQL database then Matlab script fetch that image and process the image and save its result to database from which android application fetch result and display to the user.

Help me please im stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using while loop now..

while(true)

// my code

end

as for 100 images problem.. im using cursor for fetching images from database.

this keeps my function running for infinite times.